# Need help for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I would like to show the first 200 entries and if I run it again the next 200 hundred and so on. The variable `totalResults` will be dynamically set later. If I have only 45 Entries it should show those entries, if it has, for example, 540 entries then it should only show the first 200 entries. I use a Properties File. Here is the code:

```
public class NewClass1 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int totalResults = 420; //
    int itemsperPage = 10;
    int count = 200;
    int i = 0;

    FileOutputStream output = null;
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream input = null;
    input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    //get the property value startIndex and print it out
    String iStr = prop.getProperty("i");
    int startIndex = Integer.parseInt(iStr);
    System.out.println("startIndex " + startIndex);

    //get the property value startIndex and print it out
    String iCount = prop.getProperty("count");
    int intCount = Integer.parseInt(iCount);
    System.out.println("intCount " + intCount);

    count = intCount;

    for (i = startIndex; i <= (count / itemsperPage); i++) {
        //System.out.println("count/itemsperPage "+(count / itemsperPage));
        System.out.println("count for " + count);
        System.out.println("i for  " + i);

        if (totalResults >= count) {
            System.out.println(" i " + i);
            System.out.println("last");
            output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
            //prop.setProperty("pos", strI+"0");
            String strI = "" + (i);
            prop.setProperty("i", strI);

            String strCount = "" + (count + 200);
            prop.setProperty("count", strCount);

            prop.store(output, null);

        }else{

            System.out.println("else");
            break;
        }

    }

  }

}
```

If I run this program the first time, the `config.properties` key and value
should be declared for `count=200;` and `i=1;`

The output on the first run is:

- `i for 1, i for 2, i......, i for 20`

and if I run it again:

- `i for 20, i for 21,i....., i for 40`

It shows the starting index up to 40 but there are 420 entries. Shouldn't it print out
the starting index up to 420? Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that it should keep looping after startIndex 40? What is the value of "count" at that point? What is the value of totalResults?

Comment: Part of the problem is that it's not at all clear what you're trying to do; there's a huge disconnect between what you're saying and what your code is saying.  You say you want to print the first 200 entries, but nowhere in your code do you mention entries of any kind.  Further, your loop is only iterating 20 times, which you seem to be happy about?  There are multiple unused and/or redundant variables.  I'm trying to help you to clean up the code a bit so that we can figure out what you're trying to do.  Otherwise we can't help fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get that you've already chosen an accepted answer. But if you need the solution provided to you. I've added the source code below that will achieve your intended operation.

And yes as Floegipoky has pointed out your code is not easily readable. Just make sure that the relevant code is grouped together -- that solves half your readability issues.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFile
{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
        {
                Properties config = new Properties();
                config.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

                int itemsPerPage = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("itemsPerPage"));
                int currentIndex = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("currentIndex"));
                int totalItemCount = Integer.parseInt(config.getProperty("totalItemCount"));

                if(currentIndex < totalItemCount)
                {
                        for(int iterator = 0; iterator < itemsPerPage; iterator++)
                        {
                                if(currentIndex < totalItemCount)
                                {
                                        //TODO Insert what ever processing of those batch operations here
                                        currentIndex++;
                                        continue;
                                }
                        }

                        config.setProperty("currentIndex", ((Integer)currentIndex).toString());

                        config.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"),null);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi this Code is more readable. But it has not the behavior.My english is not so good, so may i can not so good explain. I will explain for what i do need this code this will help, i hope so.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are a lot of problems here in addition to the incorrect loop condition.

First, the most obvious problem that I see: you're assigning `output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");` in your loop, which is Very Bad.

In general, this code is about 4 times longer than it needs to be, which makes it very difficult to understand.  For instance:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream input = null;
input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

// load a properties file
prop.load(input);
```

should be

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
```

The comment is really not necessary either.  Comments should be used only for things that are non-obvious, otherwise they're just distractions.

```
//get the property value startIndex and print it out
String iStr = prop.getProperty("i");
int startIndex = Integer.parseInt(iStr);
System.out.println("startIndex " + startIndex);
```

becomes

```
int startIndex = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("i"));
```

etc

Get into the habit of asking yourself these 3 questions:
1.  Can I do what I'm trying to do over several lines on fewer lines instead?
2.  What do I gain from doing it on more lines?
3.  Why am I not moving it into a separate function?

You also don't need `i` and `count` along with `startIndex` and `intCount`.  They're redundant.

Make these changes, get rid of the commented out code and the debugging-related print statements, then edit your question and I guarantee you'll get much more attention.

I would also really suggest writing out in English what you're trying to accomplish and breaking it into steps (pseudocode).  Then go through your program and reexamine the actual code that implements each step of pseudocode.  You're going to find that in some cases, you've written redundant or overly complicated code, or you're not doing what you want to do.  Plus, posting the psuedocode along with your question will help us a lot.

Above all, don't get discouraged.  We all wrote code like this at some point; getting better is a long and painful process but the more effort you put in, the faster you'll learn.

Comment: thanks for your knowledge sharing, but i still dont know how to make this loop, i tried so many time, no idea, it would great if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I do make a request to a Website this gives me a XML Response with the variables, totalresults, itemsperPage and pos: In this example the code wich deniss above wrote is: totalresults=totalItemCount, and pos=currentIndex:

This interface does gives only 200 entries once a day the totalresults could be mor than this 200
and thats the point how to loop the next day from the right position, itemsperPage is 10, 
for one request it gives a response with 10 entries in the File, if the totalItemCount is 425
in this Case the last File will have 5 entries.

the output on the console should be:

for example: 
totalItemCount is= 425

this should be the loop

"http:/query/currentIndex1" this will give back, 10 Entries.

- "http:/query/currentIndex2" this will give back the next 10 Entries
- ..........
- "http:/query/currentIndex20" this will give back the next 10 Entries" (because 20x10 makes)

if run the programm again

- "http:/query/currentIndex21" this will give back the next 10 Entries (210 Entries)
- ...........
- "http:/query/currentIndex42" this will give back the next 10 Entries ( because 42 x 10 makes 420).

May it should, there in the code another variable for the 200=Entries ?